# How to handle non-gem dependencies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what may be a stupid question. If it is, sorry.

I recently took on a Rails project that requires PhantomJS in order for its Cucumber scenarios to run properly. Unfortunately, the app doesn't say that it depends on PhantomJS, and so when the scenarios failed, it just looked like things were broken, and it wasn't really clear why.

The only way to make the errors stop was to do `brew install phantomjs`. Obviously, this is not a gem, and installing the PhantomJS gem didn't do anything, either.

**What's the proper way to handle non-gem dependencies in Rails projects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard way.

PhantomJS is a standalone application and needs to be installed as such. It would be the same as installing redis or postgreSQL if your application depended on it.

You were right to install using homebrew though, makes updating removing easier.

Comment: I accepted this answer, although not without sadness. :) This is where I'm coming from with this, by the way: http://www.12factor.net/dependencies

Comment: Ah, but the last paragraph - `Twelve-factor apps also do not rely on the implicit existence of any system tools.`, uses an example of ImageMagick, which I'd put on par with PhantomJS :)

Comment: m_x's answer makes a good point - I'd always recommend using a server config system like chef or puppet.  Not explicitly part of rails, but a great way to be confident everything is where it should be.

Comment: Yes, they're saying that you should not depend on any system tools, like ImageMagick or PhantomJS. Last sentence of that same paragraph: "If the app needs to shell out to a system tool, that tool should be vendored into the app." My question was how to vendor PhantomJS into the app. It looks like it may not be directly possible.

Comment: some gems may vendor binaries of external tools, or even have native C extensions that must be compiled on install. I'm not a big fan about this solution, because it is almost always assumed that your app will run on a *nix environment, and because it won't use standard procedures to install packages (won't use apt-get for instance).

Comment: here's documentation on how to vendor C extensions if you're interested : http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/

Comment: I agree, as I know there's no standard way to handle these dependencies but, even if I wouldn't recommend it, a gem to inject PhantomJS as a dependency exists: https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial matter. AFAIK,there is no built-in utility to declare dependencies on other things than gems / rubies. Ruby is an interpreted language, and as such may run on a variety of environments ; managing dependencies at this level would be a rather intricate task.

Many people handle this using **deployment tools** like [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) or [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/) to make sure that the environment in which runs the app is adequate, and install required dependencies if need be. Typically, you would create a rake task to do this, and either call it via capistrano, or have the user call it manually.

If you want to warn people about dependencies, an option would be to **use an initializer** to check on application boot that the required dependencies are installed on the environment, and issue a warning (or entirely shut down the app) if not.

Another option would simply to **perform dependency checking as a series of tests**. So if these tests fail you can provide detailed instructions on what is missing.

All in all, the least you can do is just to **list environment dependencies in your documentation**. Make sure this is on top of your main documentation file.

Comment: Good answer, and good suggestions. I already selected the other answer but I upvoted. I've seen the dependency checking in other frameworks (Symfony), so maybe I'll copy that idea.